# Automating tasks through java

Tags: java

Here's the problem:

1. Run a java client as a batch job on a unix box which will connect to Oracle and fetch some data.
2. Update an excel sheet (on a Windows machine) with the data fetched.
3. Create a chart/graph from the data in excel sheet.
4. Send the excel (with data & graph) in an email.

All the above steps must be performed without any manual intervention.

Could there be a better option to excel based solution? The main intent is to have a history of data fetched and have a chart created from that data.

I know there are many open source libraries available for creating charts like JFreeChart, but is there anything in the JDK that allows you to create charts? Could JavaFX be used for this problem?

In short, is it possible to do this with just jdk (without using any open source libraries)?

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [google docs spread sheet api](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/) to workaround MS-Excel

I think all that is pretty doable from Google docs, and yet, you still have the option of downloading the spread sheet.

From the link:

***Spreadsheets Data API***

> *The Spreadsheets Data API lets you access worksheet data within your own application or website. You can view and modify data, create and delete worksheets, issue structured queries, and more.*

***Spreadsheets Gadgets & Visualization API***

> *Spreadsheets Gadgets take advantage of the Google Visualization API to embed graphical comparisons of of structured data within a spreadsheet.*

Sounds like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pretty straightforward, just use Hibernate or even jdbc.
2. You should be able to update the Excel sheet with [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).  You could also try [Java Excel Designer](http://www.jxcell.net/) or http://www.moyosoft.com/jec/
3. At least one of the above should be able to create charts.
4. Just use Java Mail

You could wrap the above in ANT tasks as appropriate.